# SQL JOIN strange behavior

Tags: sql, join

I am very new to SQL.

I have two tables to merge, the following code works

```
SELECT *
FROM confirm
JOIN order ON confirm.email = order.email
```

But this one does not work for me

```
SELECT *
FROM confirm
JOIN order ON confirm.custid = order.custid
```

Everything here (email, custid) is VARCHAR(22). For the first one I get expected results but no matching results for the second one. The email and custid records are variable length between records. I also tried trim()- not avail. Any pointers?

AND custid is in the following format AB12345
-two letters and numbers

Comment: Do you have example data from both tables? If you can provide row data for table 1 and table 2 that would help give a clue.

Comment: I suppose the obvious place to start would be - are you sure that there are matches in the two tables on custid?  Because that's a pretty straightforward `join`; if there are matches, then it should return results.

Comment: I am 100% sure about the match- Jeremey

Comment: custid email Item 
PJ551080974 first@first.com 2 
PJ909008572 second@second.com 1 
RT100875256 third.third@third.com 2 

custid email cardtype authcode
PJ551080974 first@first.com Discover 36541P
PJ909008572 second@second.com Visa 56486
RT100875256 third.third@third.com Visa 23654D

Comment: This is just a data issue. Keep looking at the data and you'll find a solution. Provide your table structure.

Comment: i am not expert so you will need to help me. I am not a programmer.

Comment: Does changing your join to `JOIN order on LTRIM(RTRIM(confirm.custid)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(order.custid))` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy stated in his comment, if the "custid" does not match exactly, it will not join.

Example:
Table 1:
Email : abc@abc.com
CustId : AB12345

Email: abc2@abc.com
CustId : AB12346

Table 2:
Email: abc@abc.com
CustId : AB12345

Email: abc3@abc.com
CustId : AB12347

If you do:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B on B.CustId = A.CustId
```

Your result will be:
Email: abc@abc.com and CustId: AB12345

This is because those columns match each other. abc2 and abc3 do not match in both tables, so they will not appear in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You first go through both table check whether any matching custid is there or not,if there apply some where condition and filter it out,like select * from tblconfirm where custid="AB1234",like that chck in the case of other table,if it is there then no problem ,else no result will come.

Comment: I have tried this on both tables select * from tblconfirm where custid="AB1234" I get expected results

Comment: sorry i take that back. it works on one table only. I clearly see (visually) that there is a same custid in the table but the code does not return it. I have no idea whats going on

Comment: when i export offending table to excel, i see trailing spaces. but my trim attempt should have worked or not really!

Comment: The following is not working for me.
SELECT *
FROM confirm
JOIN order ON TRIM(confirm.custid) = TRIM(order.custid)

Comment: what an interesting mistake- the first had "/n" entered at the end by a script. I don't know how to remove it from existing set though

Comment: use rtrim or ltrim,like "select rtrim(ltrim(custid)) as CustomerID from confirm c join order o on c.custid=o.custid.it will solve white space issue .

Comment: R u using sql server..? check this :    
     MySQL: TRIM(), RTRIM(), LTRIM(),Oracle: RTRIM(), LTRIM()
    SQL Server: RTRIM(), LTRIM().Use the function accordingly.